# The Idea behind the UIInterfaceOrientaitonLandscapeRight-Left

Tags: iphone, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm very curious about why UIIntefarceOrientation value equals to -LandscapeRight when I rotate the phone to left and vice-versa.Here's the -LandscapeRight mode:

[image]

and here's the -LandscapeLeft mode:

[image]

Roughly said, before, when the phone was in -Portrait mode the speaker or the top of the phone was pointing up, now it's poiting to left. But why is it -LanscapeRight?

Comment: Are you asking for the reasoning behind why Apple has named these particular orientations LandscapeLeft and LandscapeRight?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I might suggest Apple to make it more natural. I'd try to answer the question if I were you instead of just making discouraging comments.

Comment: Sorry if you misunderstood my intention Mikayil; I wasn't trying to put a degrading comment by any means; just wanted to clarify what the question was precisely before throwing in an answer. I did put in an answer a bit later with an excerpt from the XCode documentation which shows the reasoning Apple has used for this purpose. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means the user interface has rotated to the right, not the device.  Imagine the device still (always pointing upwards) the interface would rotate.

Comment: That's a very simple and perfect explanation. Thank you buddy. I got the total understanding of it. I'll accept and vote the answer up in 3 minutes.

Comment: Indeed, that's why InterfaceOrientationLeft has the same numerical value as DeviceOrientationRight (and ditto for the other way around). If the device rotates to the right, the interface has to rotate to the left to remain upright.

Comment: No problem, have been there myself with some of this stuff ;o)

Answer (score 2):

it's all comes from the home button of iphone wheter it will be the position will be according to its home button position like in your upper image the home button on right side os the position is uiinterfaceorientationright and next one is left .

Answer (score 2):

To quote the XCode documentation:

**UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft**
The device is in landscape mode, with the device held upright and the home button on the left side. Available in iOS 2.0 and later. 
Declared in UIApplication.h.

**UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight** 
The device is in landscape mode, with the device held upright and the home button on the right side. Available in iOS 2.0 and later. 
Declared in UIApplication.h.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd post my own answer as I understood it totally .As @Magic Bullet Dave said it's the Interface orientation of which is changing according to the device itself. If we take the device and the interface separately, when we rotate the device itself to left then the interface orientation will remain right to the device. So as the name implies it is UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight not UIDeviceOrientationLadscapeRight.